# Simon Says Game unable to disable color pads during computer turn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built the simon game. It functions correctly if the user plays correctly but in an attempt to make it full proof I wanted to disable the user from clicking choices while the computer is showing the next pattern. I've tried many combinations of using the jquery .on/.off .unbind/.bind with e.preventDefault but have had no success. Can someone please help me with the solution to adding this feature.This is a codepen link if you want to see the full project as I'm only going to post what seems like relevant code below it. http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/full/vKxwWw/

HTML:

```
<div class='gameContainer'>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <a href="#" id="1" class="field blue"></a>
   <a href="#" id="2" class="field yellow "></a>
   <a href="#" id="3" class="field red"></a>
   <a href="#" id="4" class="field green"></a> 
</div><!--End of gameContainer-->
```

CSS:

```
function playComputerSequence(seq,speed){
  //Preventing pressing not working
  $('.field').each(function(){
     $(this).off('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
  //Everything below this working correctly
  var count = Number($('.count span').text());
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
     $('#'+seq[i]).addClass('on');
     var audio = new Audio(audioArray[seq[i]-1]);
     setTimeout(function(){
        audio.play();
        $('#'+seq[i]).removeClass('on');
        i++;
     },500)
     setTimeout(function(){
        if(i == count)
        {
           clearInterval(interval);
        }
     },500);
  },speed);
  $('.field').each(function(){
     $(this).off().on('click',recordUserChoice);
  });
}

function recordUserChoice(){
  userArray.push(this.id);
  var audio = new Audio(audioArray[this.id-1]);
  setTimeout(function(){
     audio.play();
  },500);
  checkSequence(userArray);
}
```

Comment: Adjit is correct, `.off()` doesn't accept an anon function in the way you've defined it. it only accepts a reference to a function name to remove that specific event handler from the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use some sort of flag to determine the state of the game.

Obviously, the `.off()` isn't doing the trick, so I would say remove all references to that. However, I believe the reason it is not working is because you are using it wrong. You don't need to use `.each()` when unbinding. That is what the selector is for, so if you use `$('.field').off('click', '**')` that should remove all delegated click handlers from any elements with `class='field'`. To read up on proper usage I would suggest looking here: http://api.jquery.com/off/

However, I still do not believe that you should be removing the delegated events. To simplify things just have a flag that can be checked to see game state.

```
var gameState = 0; //0 means the user can click, 1 means the user cannot

function playComputerSequence(seq, speed){
   gameState = 1;

   //Rest of function code
   //...

   gameState = 0;
}

function recordUserChoice(){
   if(gameState === 1) return; //if gameState is 1, jump out of the function

   //Rest of function code
   //...
}
```

While this logic works, for your situation it needs to be tailored a little differently.

At the start of your code, below your `audioArray` place the below code. This will be your `field` click handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '.field', recordUserChoice);
```

Then, one thing I realized was that `gamestate` basically immediately gets changed back to `0`, so I instead put that below where you `clearInterval(interval)` since that is what determines when the computer is done going.

```
if(i == count)
{
   clearInterval(interval);
  gamestate = 0;
  console.log(gamestate);
}
```

Then you can remove all instances of `$('.field').each()`

See this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWJLyp

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me, I tried to implement it my updated pen looks like this http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/vKxwWw

Right now during the comp sequence it's logging 0 and entering the else statement. I'm thinking possibly because of the setInterval or setTimeout in the compSequence function, not sure.

But also, if I try to change
$('.field').each(function(){
     $(this).off().on('click',recordUserChoice);
  }); 
to
$('.field).on('click',recordUserChoice);
the game breaks, like it's calling recordUserChoice twice. So I can't remove this like you suggested and test

Comment: @RawleJuglal take a look now.

Comment: Kept testing and moved the gameState = 0 to restore users ability to click into the setTimeout function with clearInterval(interval) and this solved the problem. Thank you so much for the advice. I had not even thought about using a flag to check.

Comment: @RawleJuglal glad to help. Sometimes the best solutions are the most simplistic.